# Google analytic plugins is not working wordpress

Tags: analytics

I had install GA plugin in my site. I entered the UA code manulla. However when I view the source code it shows the script as below...

```
<div class="right-content"> 
        <script type="text/javascript">//&lt;![CDATA[
        // Google Analytics for WordPress by Yoast v4.2.7 | http://yoast.com/wordpress/google-analytics/
        .....
```

Its more than a week but nothing displays. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code for your footer please?

Comment: Are you using this plugin? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/faq/

Comment: yes ... the same plugin..but i dont know why am not able to paste full footer code right here .. am soory. :(

Comment: You shouldn't have to customize your footer. The plugin should do this for you...

Comment: The plugin had the option for header and manually so i choose manually to display in footer. Then i copy the funciton and paste it in the footer inside the div.right-content  . Why isnt this working..

Comment: Did it work when you just activate the plugin and don't customize anything?

Comment: no .. nothing changess..

Comment: Please consider to mark my answer as correct if it works.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to mark as resolved.

Comment: If my answer is correct you have to just klick on the button at the left side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just activate the plugin and insert your tracking code. Don't customize your footer or anything. Why do you want to put it in the footer? Because of performance?

Comment: I remove the code from footer and set the option to "in the header (default)"  and update successfully but nothing changes..What is wrong am really noob please advice me more..

Comment: Can you paste the source output (HTML) of the site?

Comment: i removed the plugin. I download a fresh one from http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/ there is space on footer so i would like to display it on footer. But this time i had set the option to default.. why isnt this working.. :(

Comment: This is working. The script is in your header as it should be. Just wait and you should see the data coming in.

Comment: Its more than a week but i didnt see any stats in my website. Can you tell me what else i am missing.